# rails 4 - update user object and bypass model validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm following Micahel Hartl's Rails tutorial to build a sample app. I've tried to explore a bit and add some different things-- so in the Users table I've added an `account_balance` column.

The problem is that the `User` model has a bunch of validations built in:

```
validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
validates :username, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(?:\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
validates :email, presence:   true,
                  format:     { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                  uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
has_secure_password
validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
```

I have another function that attempts to update just the `account_balance` by doing:

```
buyer   = User.find(t.buyer_id)
buyer.account_balance -= item_price 
buyer.save
```

This fails to save. When I ran it in the rails console, it returned the following, which means nothing to me:

```
irb(main):055:0> u = User.first
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
=> # all the user info here
irb(main):056:0> u.account_balance = 10.00
=> 10.0
irb(main):057:0> u.save
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE (LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('test@example.com') AND "users"."id" != 1) LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
=> false
```

I am guessing that the uniqueness constraint on the email is being violated, but I don't know why this would happen on an update?

Comment: Have you tried adding the `on: :create` option to the email validation?

Comment: @Cwitty-- this does work, but I was hoping there's a way to bypass validations when you do it "internally" vs. via form submission-- since this would allow users to submit bad updates to their profile.

Comment: Gotcha. I believe you can pass options to the update_attribute method to bypass it

Comment: I'm on my phone or I would look it up

Comment: I doubt it's the uniqueness constraint.  What's in the user info?  If you've created users in the db, then added validations, you could be getting a different error.  You can always look at u.errors and see what's in there.

Comment: @Swards-- thanks for the tip-- `u.errors = @messages={:password=>["is too short (minimum is 6 characters)"]}>`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Found it. Just pass `validate: false` to the save method.

`buyer.save(validate: false)`

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations.html

Comment: Thanks! so you mean like `buyer.save(false)`?

Comment: unfortunately that didn't appear to work, it still fails and looking in the logs it appears to be running validation queries that are failing, then doing a roll back and returning false.

Comment: error message in browser is `undefined method `[]' for false:FalseClass`
`buyer.save(false)`

Comment: Maybe try passing validate: false

Answer (score 2):

```
buyer = User.find(t.buyer_id)
buyer.account_balance -= item_price 
buyer.save(validate: false) # this skips the validation
```

Comment: Could you add some details of why this should work? Code-only answers are not very useful and are subject to deletion.